# I need a help in catching the root of memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Questions: why memory leak occur? what causes it? how to fix it?

I have a server with 1 web site running. It hosts in 32bit application pool. And it grows in memory after start up to 2-3 Gb. From those 2-3 Gb 1-1.5 is memory of our managed code and we are working on it, but other 1-1.5 Gb is native memory allocated by webengine4 module. I assume it is some IIS module (output from DebugDiag 1.2):

Top 4 functions by allocation size

```
webengine4!W3_MGD_BUFFER_POOL::RentBuffer+1a  1,29 GBytes
webengine4!BUFFER::ReallocStorage+34  90.82 KBytes
webengine4!MemAlloc+24  63.45 KBytes
webengine4!MemAllocClear+24  400 Bytes
```

Sample callstack:

```
Function 
webengine4!W3_MGD_BUFFER_POOL::RentBuffer+1a 
webengine4!MgdGetBuffer+11 
System.Web.HttpResponseUnmanagedBufferElement..ctor() 
System.Web.HttpWriter.BufferData(Byte[], Int32, Int32, Boolean) 
System.Web.HttpWriter.WriteFromStream(Byte[], Int32, Int32) 
System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.InternalWrite(Byte[], Int32, Int32, Boolean) 
System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32) 
System.IO.Compression.GZipStream.Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32) 
System.Web.HttpWriter.FilterIntegrated(Boolean, System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest) 
iiscore!`WWWServerTraceProvider::GetProviderGuid'::`2'::ProviderGuid 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, Int32 ByRef, Boolean ByRef, Int32 ByRef) 
clr!InlinedCallFrame::`vftable' 
System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext, System.AsyncCallback) 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest, System.Web.HttpContext) 
clr!InlinedCallFrame::`vftable' 
0x31E672 
0x31E672 
0x31E5CD 
System_Web_ni+1d1dac 
clr!FastNExportExceptHandler 
webengine4!__delayLoadHelper2+376 
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::RequestDoWork+190 
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModulesInternal+305 
iiscore!NOTIFICATION_CONTEXT::CallModules+28 
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::DoStateGeneralEvent+36 
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::DoWork+c6 
iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::ContinueNotificationLoop+1f 
iiscore!W3_MAIN_CONTEXT::ProcessIndicateCompletion+1f 
iiscore!W3_CONTEXT::IndicateCompletion+75 
webengine4!W3_MGD_HANDLER::IndicateCompletion+3d 
webengine4!MgdIndicateCompletion+24 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef) 
clr!InlinedCallFrame::`vftable' 
DomainNeutralILStubClass.IL_STUB_PInvoke(IntPtr, System.Web.RequestNotificationStatus ByRef) 
clr!InlinedCallFrame::`vftable' 
clr!ContextTransitionFrame::`vftable' 
0x31E5CD 
System_Web_ni+1d1dac 
clr!UM2MThunk_WrapperHelper+10 
clr!UM2MThunk_Wrapper+8c 
clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+f0 
clr!UM2MDoADCallBack+c0 
0x31E628 
clr!FastNExportExceptHandler 
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+26ffa 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart 
clr!SlowClrFlsSetValue+42 
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+41b4f 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart 
clr!operator delete+41 
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart 
clr! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+41bd8 
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+4b 
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+e 
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+70 
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+1b 
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc
```

And we have such exceptions (but I think, they are more simptoms, then cause):

```
    Exception type: OutOfMemoryException 
    Exception message: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Web.HttpResponseUnmanagedBufferElement.System.Web.IHttpResponseElement.GetBytes()
   at System.Web.HttpWriter.FilterIntegrated(Boolean finalFiltering, IIS7WorkerRequest wr)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.FilterOutput()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallFilterExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

I tried and didn't find any information about this. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved.

We determined that IIS worker was under heavy CPU and memory pressure caused by drastic data growth, so GC didn't have enough resources to do its work. While we are working on real fix, I can suggest to anyone in situation like workaround: we added additional worker processes (our server is stateless), they split memory pressure between them, so GC could work and unmanaged memory gone too.

Comment: I have the same issue today, can you help me, how can solve this... I tried increasing the worker process, but its of no use... Now both worker process are taking 3 GB RAM

Comment: @51k it was a while a go, I can't remember any real details on issue, sorry. I can only assume that the problem was in slow workers (heavy CPU load), so the request queue was filling up and eat memory. Try to investigate into this, but sorry if this does not help.